# How can I attach multiple PDF files to a single email directly from a PDF viewer?

Tags: email, automation, pdf-reader, attachments

We use an indexing program (an add-in to our business software) that selects PDFs for viewing from among over 60,000 documents. It's not easy for end users to figure out where each opened PDF is located, then go and select it to attach to an Outlook email.

Thus I would like to find an *easy* way for end users to attach multiple PDF files to a single Outlook email *directly from the PDF viewer itself*. Note that there are multiple PDF viewers in use, including Acrobat Reader, Acrobat Pro, PDF Xchange Pro etc., so the solution must work independently of the actual reader in use.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Put them all into a ZIP/RAR/7zip/TAR archive...

Comment: @Karan Please see the additional info above. This should explain why I am asking for advice.

Comment: @Karan The pdf are indexed with an account#, and we have a program that selects them for viewing (But not in Explorer, so we can only open them). I was just wondering if there was a work around for this issue without completely new indexing software and integration. Is this not acceptable for superuser?

Comment: @Karan The selection program is just an add-in with our business software which can't be modified. Some users use viewers like acrobat viewer, and others use Acrobat Pro and PDF Xchange Pro. I am not necessarily looking for software. I am more asking if anyone has done this or has any ideas to share.

Comment: @Karan Yes, I meant append one after another just because I haven't seen an option for attaching more than one file to an email from to viewer. Appending them to one another would allow you to send them all.

Comment: @Karan Yes, that is much more clear. Sorry for the trouble. I just found it hard to explain.

Comment: @Karan Thanks for your help. I knew that this was an unusual question, but I thought I would give it a shot.